# Concatenate results in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I am trying to insert values into a table that come from an other (lookup) table.

The first 3 results from the table are selected and need to be concatenated before they are inserted into an other table.

How can I alter the following insert to first concatenates them with no separation characters between the 3 names (example: JohnMaxLouise)?

```
INSERT INTO Table 2 VALUES ((SELECT TOP 3 names FROM Table1 ORDER BY NEWID()))
```

I am using SQL Server 2016 so string_agg is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think this is simplest with conditional aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT (MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN name ELSE '' END) +
            MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN name ELSE '' END) +
            MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN name ELSE '' END)
           )
    FROM (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
          FROM (SELECT TOP 3 name
                FROM Table1
                ORDER BY NEWID()
               ) t
          ) t;
```

An alternative is an XML approach, but if you know you want three, then conditional aggregation (or `pivot`) works fine.

Comment: The amount of names is not the same in every case (this is a simplified example). What would the XML approach look like?

Comment: @R.Doe . . . Your question is *explicitly* about three names:  "The first 3 results".  You should ask *another* question, if you "3" is really supposed to mean something else.  If you change this question, you are going to invalidate the answers of people who have tried to help you -- changing the question can lead to downvotes on the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (names varchar(max))
declare @tab1 table ([name] varchar(100))

insert into @tab1
select 'John' union select 'Max' union select 'Louise' union select 'xxx'

insert into @tab select (select top 3 [name] + '' from @tab1 for xml path(''))

select * from @tab
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will return '1,2,3,4'

```
  DECLARE @x TABLE (i INTEGER)
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(255)
  INSERT INTO @x VALUES (1),(3),(2),(4)

  SELECT @r= STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CAST(i AS VARCHAR(max))
                  FROM @x   
                  ORDER BY i
                  FOR XML PATH(''), type
                ).value('.','varchar(255)'), 1, 1, '')
  SELECT @r
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution Overview

You can use `FOR XML PATH('')` to achieve this, just use the following command:

```
SELECT  '' + NAME 
FROM (SELECT Top 3 NAME FROM TBL_1 ORDER BY NEWID()) AS T   
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Or simple concatenation

```
SELECT  @x  = @x + NAME 
FROM (SELECT Top 3 NAME FROM TBL_1 ORDER BY NEWID()) AS T1
```

---

## Detailed Solution

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96f8c/17/1)

1. First i created the test environment using the following query

   ```
    CREATE TABLE TBL_1 (NAME Varchar(50))
    CREATE TABLE TBL_2 (NAME Varchar(50))
    INSERT INTO TBL_1 (Name) VALUES ('John'),('Max'),('Louise'),('Mark'),('Peter')
   ```
2. Then i Used the following command

   ```
   DECLARE @x varchar(255)

   SELECT  @x  = (SELECT '' + NAME 
    FROM (SELECT Top 3 NAME FROM TBL_1 ORDER BY NEWID()) AS T1   
    FOR XML PATH('') ) 

   INSERT INTO TBL_2(NAME) SELECT @x;


   SELECT * FROM TBL_2
   ```

And the Result is `JohnLouiseMax`

[image]

3. Or you can use simple concatenation to achieve this

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96f8c/18/1)

```
    DECLARE @x varchar(255)
    SET @x = ''

    SELECT  @x  = @x + NAME 
    FROM (SELECT Top 3 NAME FROM TBL_1 ORDER BY NEWID()) AS T1  


    INSERT INTO TBL_2(NAME) SELECT @x;


    SELECT * FROM TBL_2
```